# Install Visual Studio 2010 error

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am using Window 7 pro x64. I had istalled VS 2010 pro. After that, I uninstalled it and replaced with VS 2012 ulti. Now, I need the VS 2010 but i can't install it. I try to install both pro and ulti version from .iso file but i get the same error. The installer quit suddenly  after a few second and the window log records two error:

-The first:

```
Faulting application name: setup.exe_Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010, version: 10.0.30319.1, time stamp: 0x4ba20d29
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7ba58
Exception code: 0xc0000006
Fault offset: 0x0003dccf
Faulting process id: 0x1170
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf728abd52e628
Faulting application path: F:\setup\setup.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
Report Id: fb6a8ef5-de7d-11e3-ada9-70f39529732e
```

-And the second:

```
Windows cannot access the file F:\setup\sqmapi.dll for one of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network connection, the disk that the
file is stored on, or the storage drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows closed the program Suite Integration Toolkit
Executable because of this error.
Program: Suite Integration Toolkit Executable
File: F:\setup\sqmapi.dll
The error value is listed in the Additional Data section.

User Action
1. Open the file again. This situation might be a temporary problem that corrects itself when the program runs again.
2. If the file still cannot be accessed and
- It is on the network, your network administrator should verify that there is not a problem with the network and that the server can be
contacted.
- It is on a removable disk, for example, a floppy disk or CD-ROM, verify that the disk is fully inserted into the computer.
3. Check and repair the file system by running CHKDSK. To run CHKDSK, click Start, click Run, type CMD, and then click OK. At the command prompt,
type CHKDSK /F, and then press ENTER.
4. If the problem persists, restore the file from a backup copy.
5. Determine whether other files on the same disk can be opened. If not, the disk might be damaged. If it is a hard disk, contact your administrator or
computer hardware vendor for further assistance.

Additional Data
Error value: C0000023
Disk type: 5
```

I try to uninstall .Net 4.5 and install .Net 4.0 but it not help. I run the system file checker and hard drive checker but no error. Then i download the ntdll.dll and sqmapi.dll to replace these files in my computer but it also not help. 
I think the .iso file still good because it still run in my friend computer.

So anyone suggest a solution ?

Comment: @oleksii: take a closer look at the close reason, particularly the phrase 'unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming'.  Visual Studio **is** a tool used primarily for programming.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: Thanks, i think this topic is not off-topic!

Comment: there are a couple possibilities here, but I don't really know if any are a solution.  the most likely situation is that this has nothing to do with VS2012 at all, but a bad removal of the original VS2010 (or it's SP1).  It is most likely not able to update the `sqmapi.dll` because a newer version exists and is in use.  I would check for any leftover VS2010 items that didn't uninstall, or try using `sfc /scannow` to see if the `sqmapi.dll` gets replaced.

Comment: Thank you, but i try using both sfc /scannow and recover my OS (i had a .GHO file) but they aren't help

Comment: hmm, it didn't install correctly from a backup copy of your OS? That is definitely suspicious, but points to some sort of OS corruption.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After i scan my computer with avira and delete some file buildlog in D drive(in my computer, C drive for OS and software, D drive for data), the installer work normally!

But i don't understand why some file buildlog in D drive can make VS can't install?

Comment: Ask this question in a new question, not in an answer.